# ColdFusion Application.cfc onRequestStart Session scope

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I have an application written in ColdFusion that allows users to log in.  My login page is in the root directory in a sub-directory called "login".  During the login process, the system checks the username and password against my database, and assuming they are legit, it sets a Session variable of "Session.LOGIN_ID".  At the bottom of my login script, I can print the login_id to the browser without any problem.  However, the last part of my login script is to redirect the user to the main home page, which is located in the root directory in a sub-directory called "main", and once in awhile the page fails to load and rather directs the user back to the login screen with a message stating that their session has ended due to inactivity.

I have a Application.cfc file defined in the "main" folder, with a onRequestStart method defined that checks for the Session.LOGIN_ID being defined.  If it is not, it redirects the user back to the login page and shows the message that their session has ended due to inactivity.

My question is, why does my session variable not present in the onRequestStart method?  It's strange because if I clear my browser cache and login, I'm able to log in without any problem.

Does this make sense to anyone?  Any suggestions as to what I could look for that could be causing this problem?  I tried to dump the session vars using cfdump var=#session# from within the onRequestStart method and CF throws and error stating that SESSION is undefined.

**UPDATE**

In response to Adam's request, there are not multiple domains involved.  Also, no switching from HTTP to HTTPS.  The login page however is not bound by the Application.cfc because the login page is located in my "login" folder.  The Application.cfc file is located in the "main" folder, along with the other components of my application.  As far as the screen shot of the cfdump, I don't want to offend anyone but I can't really post the screen shot due to the fact that it contains information pertaining the site and I'm not authorized to post such information.  I can say that when I try to do a cfdump of the session scope, it DOES show a few items in the list such as cfid, tokenid etc.  However the session.login_ID is not present.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so taking the suggestion from Frank I have the onRequestStart method set up so that it sends me an email with a dump of the session and cgi scope.  I found the following.  In the Session dump, the cfid is equal to 4830, and the cftoken starts with b8e0d5...   However, in the CGI dump, under HTTP_COOKIE, the value says CFID=4609; CFTOKEN=dd15bc0....  Are they supposed to match?

Comment: What version of CF are you using?

Comment: @FrankTudor - ColdFusion 10

Comment: Can you pls update your question: copy & paste the exact code for the `<cfdump>` and the exact error message copy and pasted from the screen. From what you *describe*, it all sounds legit. Are there different domain names involved, or switching between HTTP/HTTPS? Can it happen occasionally for *any* user, or just some users? It sounds to me like your session cookies aren't sticking, for some reason, so you're getting a new CFID/CFTOKEN / JSESSIONID each request.

Comment: I am not running that.  I bet Adam or Henry would have insight.

Comment: So basically your session doesn't persit, you have a user_id disappearing but you are not sure what that happens.  The onRequestSession redirects the user if it is not there?  All my assumptions correct?  Comment out your redirect (if you can) or create an if statement that looks for your ip address using the cgi.remote_addr and block it just for your IP if you don't know it you can go to google and type what is my IP in search field and cut and paste that.  The point is if you can stop the redirect I bet you can get a step closer to solving your problem.

Comment: @FrankTudor, my directory structure has we'll say 2 folders off the root.  One called login, and one called main.  The only application.cfc file on the site is located in the main folder.  When a user visits the site, they are presented with the login page (located in the root folder, not inside any subfolder)  When they submit the login form, it validates using a coldfusion page that is located in the login folder.  The script pulls their user id and stores it as Session.Login_ID, then redirects them to the main/index.cfm page.

Comment: @FrankTudor It's when they hit this page that the Application.cfc fires and the onRequestStart method is triggered.  The onRequestStart method says CFIF (NOT ISDEFINED('SESSION.LOGIN_ID') ..redirect to login page and  show error message that session has ended.

Comment: @Phil Yes, ok, so they (the user) clicks through a page, then another page then bam redirect is triggered.  How do you know what page it is coming from? How about add an email to that if statement (for a short while that has cfdumps that shows you your cgi and anything else useful to see if there is a pattern?

Comment: @FrankTudor updated the question following your suggestion.  My CGI dump shows a CFID=4609; CFTOKEN=dd15bc0....   where my SESSION dump shows the CFID=4830 and the CFTOKEN=b8e0d5...   Should these items match?  Could that be the culprit?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Based on what you said in your question, find the piece of code that does the re-direct.  Add a cfmail tag that includes cfdumps of the sesssion scope, plus any other data that might be useful.

Comment: @phil One are cookies and the others are sessions they can be different.  Because your cookies could have been set in a different instance of your site visit and if you don't explicitly set your cookie vars to match your session vars (which not all people need to do that) they are then set by coldfusion and will definitely be different. So does your system bunk out if these two don't explicitly match, like do you look at your cookies sometimes and your session vars another? Comparing these things back and forth could create a problem.

Comment: @FrankTudor No we strictly use the Session scope for storing user variables and information.  I just noticed that the items didnt match in the dump and figured I'd mention it in case they SHOULD match.

Comment: @phil without kicking you out of your chair, there is not much more I can do for you from here.  You know your app better than I do.  I think you need to aggregate data via these emails, see if you can pack in more information in them, then go for a drive, sleep on it, and your solution will present itself. Or if your company is draconian then frenzy up a fix good or not very good to CYA for another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the situation was resolved by enabling J2EE sessions variables from within CF Administrator.  See related post here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1058200

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment in response to, "I just noticed that the items didnt match in the dump and figured I'd mention it in case they SHOULD match".

Whether or not they should match is up to the programmer, not us on StackOverflow.  However, you debug this sort of things as follows.

```
 if(actual result == expected result)
 output 'yes'
 else
 output 'no' and the actual result and the expected result
```

Comment: ....not a helpful comment.  The way the session management works in ColdFusion is something relatively new to me.  I was asking IF they should match, because I wasn't sure.  I know what's happening, I just don't understand why.

Comment: @Phil Listen to Dan he is very knowledgeable with CF stuff and is providing a logical construct for your mind (since we have little else to go on). Now. Another thing that would be helpful for an update to your question...What is the frequency of these events happening? What is the createtime on your session stuff? Could this naturally fall off for a user like sessiontimeout=#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)# (30 minutes) and a user goes inactive clicks next and reroutes are triggered then calls and complains causing you to assume something is wrong when it is not? Could that be?

Comment: @Phil Also you mentioned two subdirectories you mentioned them for a reason...do sessions jump between the two directories? and do they jump directories without any problems?  Or are the frequency of session failures happening as a result of jumping across?